# Weird lines on normal map

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, baking, normal-map

How do I solve this? Weird lines on mesh.

Set to non-color btw.

[image]

[image]

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjwLw.png)

[image: List item]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please include a little more information. At least a wireframe of your object and a screenshot of your node setup and/or share your blend file. Maybe also mark the weird lines you are referring to in your screenshot.
Consider a look here for some guidance https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
At this point my best guess is that it's a subdivision or smooth shading issue but we would need more info to provide a good answer.

Comment: @GeorgFK Edited, hope this clears it up.

Comment: can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Sorry, rather not... This is a game asset and blende exchange explicitly states it can anyway edit my user content AND the granted right to "irrevocable, non-exclusive, royalty-free license to use, reproduce, adapt, publish, translate and distribute your user content in any existing or future media."

Comment: just provide the geometry part that is problematic and save it in a separate file. anything that will reproduce your problem else we cannot really help you.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Ok then, here. 

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sO9GoMly" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sO9GoMly/)

Comment: There is a seam and you those 2 faces are on different parts of the UV map so it can never be smooth. you will always have that line unless you manually texture painted to "fuse" it. https://snipboard.io/uI6Az4.jpg

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie What about the other mesh with no seams interfering with it? Reminder, using "Main" UV Map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your model is what's causing this, I went in and looked at your normal maps and the bevels are present in the normal map here:
[image: NormalA]
[image: NormalB]
[image: NormalC]

So to test I disabled the Normal map in the node editor and found that the bevels are not showing in your texture images but the model is still showing the bevels.
[image: Object]

This means you need to fix the model, It may be that there aren't enough subdivisions and the lines are cause from too few polygons and it cant create the curvature smoothly. I would try to maybe subdivide the mesh and make sure your topology is smooth enough.

Comment: Yup! I made sure to set margins and edit UVs for conflicting issues.

Comment: Can you post your normal map image?

Comment: Wait there might be something else as well with the orientation of the UV shells, can you post your UV map as well

Comment: Have you tried adding a Texture coordinate Node in the shader and connecting The UV dot to the Vector on the normal image node

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YkDyChz.png

Sure here.

Comment: also your blender Exchange file doesn't have to materials or maps in question so I can really diagnose from it. You would have to pack the materials into the blend file before you upload it.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=5A9bVDQ8" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5A9bVDQ8/)

Oh sorry, fixed it! Here.

Comment: OH That is MUCH MUCH Better, Ill get to cracking and see what I can find

Comment: Oh reminder, I'm using the "MAIN" uv map. So ignore the other weird uv maps.

Comment: Ya no problem I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: You've just got some "problem geometry" in your object that you need to address, unless this is a small item in the game, then you can probably just get away with it.

Comment: Yeah I try to keep poly count low cause the dude I'm working with prefers if the poly count is under a certain threshold... I'll keep this in mind in the future, thanks!

Comment: Low poly counts are definitely nice, but Beauty comes with polygons XD, Hope you can fix is without adding too many :)